# calculating correlation for every group of id using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, correlation

I have two tables in sql

first one is:

| id | Date _time | Norms | value | Avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 00:00:00 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 01:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 02:00:00 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | . | . | . | . |
| 1 | . | . | . | . |
| 1 | . | . | . | . |
| 1 | 2020-12-2 23:00:00 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-11-14 00:00:00 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020-11-14 01:00:00 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020-11-14 02:00:00 | -1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | . | . | . | . |
| 2 | . | . | . | . |
| 2 | . | . | . | . |
| 2 | 2020-01-06 23:00:00 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 2020-12-2 23:00:00 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2020-11-14 00:00:00 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 2020-11-14 01:00:00 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2020-11-14 02:00:00 | -1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | . | . | . | . |
| 3 | . | . | . | . |
| 3 | . | . | . | . |
| 3 | 2020-01-06 23:00:00 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |  |
| 20 | 2020-12-2 23:00:00 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 20 | 2020-11-14 00:00:00 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 20 | 2020-11-14 01:00:00 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 20 | 2020-11-14 02:00:00 | -1 | 2 | 3 |

and the second table:

| id | closest_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 10 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 8 |

How can I calculate correlation between group of "norm" related to each pair of id s in table1 that are closest to each other (based on table 2) ? the output should be a table like:

| id | correlation |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 0.005 |
| 3 | . |
| 4 | . |
| 5 | . |
| 6 | . |
| 7 | . |
| 8 | . |
| 9 | . |
| 10 | . |

Answer (score 0):

For clarity's sake, let's call `data` the first table and `relations` the second one. You need to construct a query that outputs each observation in the `data` table (let's call it `first`) with the observation in the `data` table (let's call it `second`) having `second.id = first.closest_id` and the same observation timestamp:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM data AS first
JOIN relations ON relations.id = first.id
JOIN data AS second ON second.id = relations.closest_id AND second.date_time = first.date_time
```

Then it is just a matter of grouping by id and using the Postgres function [corr(Y, X)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-STATISTICS-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT first.id AS id, corr(first.norms, second.norms) AS correlation
FROM data AS first
JOIN relations ON relations.id = first.id
JOIN data AS second ON second.id = relations.closest_id AND second.date_time = first.date_time
GROUP BY first.id, second.id
```